# I'm getting a type error and I'm not sure why

Tags: python, typeerror, traceback

I am using Python 2.5. I am not sure what's going wrong. I've tried this a million different ways and I am so confused.

[image]

Here is my code:

```
import math

quad_function = "(a * x^2) + b * x + c"
print "A quadratic function is:" + quad_function

a_input = raw_input("Is 'a' given?")
b_input = raw_input("Is 'b' given?")
c_input = raw_input("Is 'c' given?")
x_input = raw_input("Are any of the solutions         given?")

if a_input == "yes":
    a = int(raw_input("What is 'a'?"))
if b_input == "yes":
    b = int(raw_input("What is 'b'?"))
if c_input == "yes":
    c = int(raw_input("What is 'c'?"))
if x_input == "one":
    x_1 = int(raw_input("What is the first     solution?"))
if x_input == "both":
    x_1 = int(raw_input("What is the first solution"))
x_2 = int(raw_input("What is the second solution"))

print 'The quadratic function is:' + str(a) + 'x^2'     + '+' + str(b) + 'x' + "+" + str(c)

d = b ** 2 - 4*a*c
if d > 1:
    num_roots = 2
if d == 1:
    num_roots = 1
if d < 1:
    num_roots = 0
print "There are " + str(num_roots) + " roots"

if x_input == "no" and d > 2 and a_input == 'yes' and b_input == 'yes' and c_input == 'yes':
x1 = float(((-b) + math.sqrt(d))/(2*a))
x2 = float(((-b) - math.sqrt(d))/(2*a))
print "The two solutions are: " + str(x1) * "and " + str(x2)
```

Comment: If a b c are not given, they are not defined then? And with the answer by ayush, this question could be classified/closed as a simple typographical error.

Comment: Can be closed under: _This question was caused by a problem that can no longer be reproduced or a simple typographical error. While similar questions may be on-topic here, this one was resolved in a manner unlikely to help future readers_.

Comment: Pro tips: homework questions are welcome here. However, it is best to ask confidently. Don't be chatty or beg, it's like asking for downvotes. "Please halp me", "Be nice to me", "Thanks in advance" are all best refrained from. We like succinct questions here anyway.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've used an asterisk where you intended to use a plus sign. Replace

```
print "The two solutions are: " + str(x1) * "and " + str(x2)
```

with

```
print "The two solutions are: " + str(x1) + "and " + str(x2)
```